# what's wrong with my method insert of binary search tree?

Tags: python, insert, binary-search-tree

```
from random import randint


class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None, left_child=None, right_child=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left_child = left_child
        self.right_child = right_child


class BinarySearchTree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Node()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'bst'

    def insert(self, root, value):
        if root.value is None:
            node = Node(value)
            root = node
        else:
            if value < root.value:
                self.insert(root.left_child, value)
            else:
                self.insert(root.right_child, value)

bst = BinarySearchTree()
data = []
for i in range(100):
    data.append(randint(0,100))
    bst.insert(bst.root, data[i])
print(bst.root.value)
```

I insert some nodes to the binary search tree, but all nodes of binary tree are still None. Are there anyone who can help me figure this out? Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are not setting any value to `Node.left_child` or `Node.right_child` apart from `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up your references.

If you instantiate your BST, you make its root a `Node()`. Absolutely right. When inserting, you check for the value of this node (in the first step). Still okay. Then, you assign a new instance of `Node`to a **local** variable, which you will not be able to access afterwards.

In addition, your logic of creating new `Node`s is improper. You must check for root itself to be `None` before testing its value. Otherwise, you'll never make children ;_;

Here's your fix:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None, left_child=None, right_child=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left_child = left_child
        self.right_child = right_child


class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Node()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'bst'

    def insert(self, root, value):
        if root is None:
            root = Node()
        if root.value is None:
            root.value = value
        else:
            if value < root.value:
                self.insert(root.left_child, value)
            else:
                self.insert(root.right_child, value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bst = BinarySearchTree()
    data = []
    for i in range(100):
        data.append(randint(0,100))
        bst.insert(bst.root, data[i])
    print(bst.root.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Saying `root = node` is just making `root` reference something else.  The object that was passed in is just no longer being referenced by `root`.  It does not change the object that was passed in.  Instead, say `for k,v in vars(node).items(): setattr(root, k, v)`

Comment: um... please use `vars(node)` instead of `dir(node)` or you will end up setting bound methods and other undesired values like `__dict__` to the other object which causes a lot of problems.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: Very good thing to note.  As long as I'm using a dictionary, I made it a little more efficient.

Comment: I was going to suggest using `.items()` but felt it was too much code to add in a comment.  Thank you for changing.